# How to enable pkg-config?

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5, archlinux, pkg-config

Well, I have a little problem around here and not sure how to fix it.

I have to cross-compile qt5 for the raspberryPI, so I followed the beginners guide: [RaspberryPi Beginners Guide](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide)

My OS is ArchLinux x86_64 what make some things a little difficult cause the guide is for ubuntu / debian.

So after installing some packages the guide works until the following line:

```
  ./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
```

In phase 2 of this "configuration" I get the following output:

```
Running configuration tests (phase 2)...
Warning: Disabling pkg-config since PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR is not set and
the host's .pc files would be used (even if you set PKG_CONFIG_PATH).
Set this variable to the directory that contains target .pc files
for pkg-config to function correctly when cross-compiling or
use -pkg-config to override this test.
Note: PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR automatically set to /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs

Could not determine the target architecture!
Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to see the final report.
The OpenGL ES 2.0 functionality test failed!
Use of pkg-config is not enabled, maybe you want to pass -pkg-config?
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2, QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2 in
/home/test23/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++.
```

-

```
Set this varibale to the directory that contains target .pc files:
```

How do I find out which directory I need ?

How to set the variable right?

It is necessery or is there another way to do that?

```
Use of pkg-config is not enabled:
```

So how can I enable use of pkg-config?

```
You need to modify the include and library search paths:
```

Which value I have to set for the specified variables?
Is it necessary to do that ?

Is there some package / driver or something else I have to install?

I allready trying to find out the $PKG_CONFIG_PATH by:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

but I only get an emtpy line...

I really would appreciate your help in this situation, because I don´t find some literature or wiki which contains information about such a problem.

Comment: You could try using `BuildRoot` or `Yocto` projects.

Comment: Do you have pkg-config package installed `pacman -Q pkg-config`?

Comment: Yes,      pkg-config 0.29-1